# Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm

I installed visual studio 2015 and able to compile and run c++ test application within the IDE.

My npm installer is throwing the error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
```

When I install visual studio 2013, I don't get this error.  The libraries this npm project uses is based on visual studio 2015.

Is there something extra I need to do after the Visual studio 2015 install that I don't need to do in visual studio 2013?

Comment: Just typing "vcbuild.exe" in the Google query box is enough to find two existing questions at SO that describe this problem and its solution.

Comment: Not quite this simple.  Visual studio 2015 changed name of compiler and I can't switch to 2013 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides an npm package that solves all these native build issues without the need to install visual studio.

"windows-build-tools": "^1.3.2"